# Need to generate roll no for each student from the user?

Tags: java, arrays, function, class, object

I need to get unique roll no from each   student.

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Studentform {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int length = 3;

        Studb[] studs = new Studb[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (Studb s : studs) {
                readStudent(i);

            }
        }

    }

    static void readStudent(int i) {
        int rollno = 1001;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your age:");
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        Studb stud = new Studb(name, age, rollno++);
        System.out.println(stud);

    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of ways to generate it - AtomicInteger, UUID etc. If it is an int, you can use AtomicInteger

Comment: You are already looping with an `int i` there, which you have passed in. Just use that and it will end up to be unique.

Comment: I just want to print the scanned value with unique roll no

Comment: Use an AtomicInteger https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html

Comment: And why do you have redundant for loops?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in that and it'll also end up to be unique. Like following:

```
static void readStudent(int i) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your age:");
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        Studb stud = new Studb(name, age, i);
        System.out.println(stud);

    }
```

Or you can add i value in rollno like Following:

```
static void readStudent(int i) {
        int rollno = 1000+i;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");
        String name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Enter your age:");
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        Studb stud = new Studb(name, age, rollno);
        System.out.println(stud);

    }
```

Comment: ya but the loop is running a single time only.But I need to run all the  values according to length

Comment: content is not storing in loop

Answer (score 0):

```
    package test;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Studentform {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int length = 3;

            Studb[] studs = new Studb[length];

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                studs[i] = readStudent(i);

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                System.out.println(studs[i]);

            }

        }

        static Studb readStudent(int i) {
            int rollno = 1000+i++;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your name:");
            String name = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter your age:");
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            return new Studb(name, age, rollno);
            //System.out.println(stud);
            //return stud;
        }
    }
```